# Understanding meaning of ここまで来ると

Tags: grammar, meaning

What exactly does ここまで来ると mean, and how do I understand it in the below context? What is the subject that is doing the verb 来る?

Looking online one definition of 来る is "事態が進んで、ある状態に至る" which I guess is the definition of this 来る but I still don't quite understand how it works.

> 「ただでさえ仁乃は混乱しやすい頭してんだから、もっとハッピーにさせてあげなさいよ」
>
> 「それってつまり手のひらの上で踊らせろってことなんじゃ……」
>
> 「……先生も幸村くんも、基本的にわたしをバカにしてるよね？」
>
> 「そ、そんなことはない」
>
> 「そう、そんなこたぁない」
>
> 「じー……」
>
> 疑いの眼差しだ。さすがの仁乃も**ここまで来ると**騙されない。
>
> 「いいもん。どうせバカだもん……」

Comment: I think you're referring to the right definition. This 来る means "(for a situation) to turn out".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Japanese or Korean the subject can often be omitted. So, 仁乃 is not the subject of 来る。The subject is something like "it" in English. Think about an expression like, "When it comes to". The "it" is not something specific, it is just an abstract thing. If we have to specify the subject of 来る, it could be 状況 (circumstance). But that is not something worth mentioning so it is omitted.

So, the meaning of the sentence is something like, "**When it has become this obvious**, even a dull person like 仁乃 cannot help but notice it."